# Electrical engineering - equivalent resistance

Tags: circuit-analysis, short-circuit, thevenin

[image]

The answer is 0.5 ohm but I couldn't solve it.

What I did is this > R3 is shorted and after doing the series - parallel i obtain the following  :

(( (R2 // R5) in series with R4 ) // R0 ) in series with R1

I don't know where is my mistake , maybe R3 shouldn't be shortened if so when should I eliminate a resistor because it short circuited ?

Comment: You should try using a Y-Delta conversion to simplify the circuit

Comment: First remove \$R_4\$ and \$R_5\$ from your schematic by deleting them and the wires to them. Now you just have two identical dividers. Their midpoints will have the same voltage, so if you add back \$R_4\$ it won't matter as there will be no possible voltage across it. So you can leave it removed and not bother adding it back. Now putting back \$R_5\$ you just have \$R_5\$ in parallel with two dividers also in parallel. That you can work out. Done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\$R_5\$ is between \$A\$ and \$B\$

Since they are all the same resistance, no current will flow through \$R_4\$. This means that I can remove \$R_4\$ from the circuit.

\$R_0 + R_1\$ is between \$A\$ and \$B\$

\$R_2 + R_3\$ is between \$A\$ and \$B\$

So you have 3 branches in parallel.

The total resistance will be:

$$\frac{1}{\frac{1}{R_0+R_1}+\frac{1}{R_2+R_3}+\frac{1}{R_5}} = 0.5 Ω$$

---

Why can I say that no current will flow through \$R_4\$?

That is because the potential across \$R_4\$ will be 0 Volt. The node between \$R_0\$ and \$R_1\$ will have the exact same potential as the node between \$R_2\$ and \$R_3\$.

If we make use of ohm's law \$V=I×R\$, we have \$V=0\$ and \$R=R_4=1Ω\$. So let's move the equation around so we can find \$I\$.

\$I = \frac{V}{R}=\frac{0 V}{1Ω} = 0\$ A

There is no current flowing through that resistor, that means that if the resistance would be \$\infty\$ Ω, it would also be \$0\$ A flowing through that resistor.

Do you know what else is \$\infty\$ Ω? Something that is not connected = not part of the circuit.

Comment: Can you explain more why no current pass thru R4 ?

Comment: Harry already gave you the answer.  R0 and R1 form a voltage divider, the potential in the middle will be (Va + Vb) / 2 because R0 = R1.  The same thing happens with R2 and R3, the voltage of the node will be (Va + Vb) / 2.  Since there is no potential difference between the two ends of R4, no current flows (I = E / R and E = 0 so I = 0).